# Got error on installation of strapi. something went wrong installing the "sharp" module. How to fix it

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, strapi, sharp

sharp module is present in node_module folder but why it's showing error . I don't know what's the reason behind.Even I install sharp.but still getting error.If anyone know how to fix sharp module ?. In addition. when I try to install with yarn than got something else error.
***C:\Users\4' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.***

Error :
Could not load js config file D:\Mohsin-Work-Space\Strapi Backend Practice Session\project_strapi23\node_modules@strapi\plugin-upload\strapi-server.js:
Something went wrong installing the "sharp" module

The specified module could not be found.
\?\D:\Mohsin-Work-Space\Strapi Backend Practice Session\project_strapi23\node_modules@strapi\plugin-upload\node_modules\sharp\build\Release\sharp-win32-x64.node

Comment: A few context/source code would be nice

Comment: You just copied the error message. You should ask an actual question, along with outlining what you've already tried and what did/didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I also run into this problem during my installation, and how I managed to fix it was to run the installation command as administrator and everything worked.